# cllocationmanager - cllocation response object timestamp always less than one second old, why?

Tags: iphone, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

using the core location iphone api to get some locations.

It works fine, but one thing puzzles me. The ones i get back, i calculate their 'age' using the following code:

```
NSDate *eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

i then print the age using:

```
NSLog(@"didupdateToLocation! lat: %f, lon: %f, accuracy: %f, age: %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude, newLocation.horizontalAccuracy, locationAge);
```

In my output, the age is ALWAYS less than one second. log examples:

```
2011-09-15 14:31:40.417 Nuba[1393:707] didupdateToLocation! lat: 59.340484, lon: 18.052089, accuracy: 816.373281, age: 0.055586
2011-09-15 14:31:40.495 Nuba[1393:707] didupdateToLocation! lat: 59.340484, lon: 18.052089, accuracy: 816.373281, age: 0.125578
2011-09-15 14:31:40.565 Nuba[1393:707] didupdateToLocation! lat: 59.340477, lon: 18.051996, accuracy: 999.848989, age: 0.019127
```

Why is this? Surely the first time, the phone didn't just "happen" to have a less than one second old location cached, every time?

Am i doing something wrong when i'm calculating the age?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calculating correctly.  If location services are already in use by a background app or if you have cellular service then you could easily have a location already when you're app starts.

You don't display the accuracy so it's possible (likely) that your first location is low accuracy (ie: > 1000m horizontal error) location calculated from cell tower triangulation which is always available when the phone is on the cellular network.

Comment: I just feel that its strange that the ages are *always* that short age. I have a sample size of hundreds now, almost never older than one second. On Android, you get tons of responses that are older. Yeah, i do print the accuracy too, a bit down :) And it does get better sometimes, tower triangulation in Stockholm is usually 600-900meters accuracy. But unless the gps hooks up or i'm on a wifi, the triangulation doesn't usually get better though.